# How to gain research experience after undergrad?

Tags: computer-science, science, india

After graduating with B.Sc Computer Science last year, I got interested in compilers and kernel. I started reading research papers and finally decided to pursue masters, but most programs favour research experience.

I am an Indian student and reseach opportunities are very rare here, I approached my professors but haven't received any positive responses. Is there some other way I can gain some research experience, especially in India? or find someone who can guide me to perform some research Individually, Since I'm not sure where to start exactly.

Comment: Which university requires research experience to enroll into masters? Are you talking about M.Sc CS? As far as I know, most universities just conduct entrance exams, and some of those conduct interview.

Comment: I want to apply for masters in canada, MASc CS. Even though research experience is optional, I still need to prove my research potential, where some experience definitely helps.